# AnkhSvn - Resolved a file by mistake without address all conflicts

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2015, ankhsvn

I'm using SVN with AnkhSVN. There's a file that I updated from the server which is conflicting with my local modifications.

I click Resolve Conflicts by mistake and now the conflict state is gone and the conflict markers are everywhere in my file.

How can I revert its state to "Conflicted" so I can use the tool to merge the conflicts?

Comment: Have you tried just using revert? I've run into stuff like this with ankh. In this case I'd probably make a backup of the conflict marker-riddled file and then use the Revert feature on that file. Then try and pull out the changes you made from your backup and update the reverted file.

Comment: When I clicked [resolve conflicts] by accident, the revert options disappears. And the marker-riddled file is now considered 'resolved' or 'normal' by SVN, hence the problem.